# How to secure a single page app with different authentication based on parameter value using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oracle-apex

I'm doing a web app using spring boot. The web app is basically a tool/builder for creating web applications similar to that of Oracle Application Express. It has only one page/view (f.html) which is dynamic in the sense that it shows different layouts based on parameter value. There is only one parameter named "p". This parameter is a concatenation of the application id/code, page id/code etc.

For ex:

f?p=HR:EMPLOYEES:[items]:[values] which basically means HR is the application and EMPLOYEES is the page and [items] is optional for page items and [values] is optional for item values. Parsing will be handled by the Controller.

I have a database with tables for this. For ex:

```
create table web_applications (
  id                  bigint            auto_increment
, code                varchar(30)   not null
, name                varchar(255)  not null
, description         varchar(255)
, workspace_id        bigint
, created_on          datetime
, last_updated_on     datetime
, created_by          bigint
, last_updated_by     bigint
, primary key ( id )  );

create table web_pages (
    id                  bigint            auto_increment
  , code                varchar(30)   not null
  , name                varchar(255)  not null
  , application_id      bigint
  , created_on          datetime
  , last_updated_on     datetime
  , created_by          bigint
  , last_updated_by     bigint
  , primary key ( id )
  , foreign key ( application_id ) references web_applications ( id )
);

create table web_regions (
    id                  bigint             auto_increment
  , name                varchar(255)  not null
  , region_type         varchar(30)   not null
  , sequence_id         int           not null
  , page_id             bigint
  , parent_region_id    bigint
  , source_type         varchar(30)
  , source_table_or_query varchar(4000)
  , created_on          datetime
  , last_updated_on     datetime
  , created_by          bigint
  , last_updated_by     bigint
  , primary key ( id )
  , foreign key ( page_id ) references web_pages ( id )
  , foreign key ( parent_region_id ) references web_regions ( id )
);
```

And so on... These tables contains data for the layout of the page.

I also have a single controller which basically pulls data from the tables mentioned above. The data pull will determine the layout of the page/view in the spring boot app.

Going back to the sample above, I have a record in the web_applications table for HR and a record in the web_pages for the EMPLOYEES. Then I have region records for the EMPLOYEES page which in summary would be like a table showing employees data. Now let's say I have another record in the web_page table for a single EMPLOYEE. Think of the EMPLOYEES page as a Report page (with link to EMPLOYEE page) and the EMPLOYEE page as a CRUD page.

Now when running the spring boot web app, the url will look something like:

https://localhost/f?p=HR:EMPLOYEES::

Which will then display the appropriate layout. Clicking a row will basically call the same spring boot page f?p=HR:EMPLOYEE:ID:1 but will now display a different layout.

Now on to the requirement. So basically HR is an application of this web app (not Spring Boot). Let's say I want to build another application for ex: SALES with pages for CUSTOMERS, CUSTOMER, PRODUCTS, PRODUCT. Again these will have corresponding records in the tables web_applications (SALES), web_pages (CUSTOMERS, CUSTOMER, PRODUCTS and PRODUCT).

So now we have 2 applications in this tool. HR and SALES which have the following URLS;

https://localhost/f?p=HR:::

https://localhost/f?p=SALES:::

What I'm trying to do is have separate authentications for https://localhost/f?p=HR::: and another for https://localhost/f?p=SALES:::

But in Spring Boot's perspective, this is only a single application. Does spring boot security support multiple authentications/sessions in a single application?

Comment: What do you mean by `application`? Do you have more than one Spring Boot application? In this case every application is using a different port or at least a different context root. AFAIK you can't share a context root (in your case `f`) for different applications. Or do you use a proxy to route the request to the different applications using the parameter `p`?

Comment: Updated the title and question to further explain the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

f is a function in the database, where p represents the relevant application built within APEX. Each application has its own set of security settings, and this includes authentication method.

Out of the box, each application is considered separate, and if you navigate to a different application, you'll need to authenticate again. This is managed internally I believe with a combination of cookies and database rows.

If you want to modularise your applications, then you can have them all behave is if they're one application using *Workspace Sharing* http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2019/01/oracle-apex-application-session-sharing.html

I'm not sure what 'sprint boot' is.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Spring Boot is a java framework. I'm trying to check if it's capable of the same logic.